# Installing folium in Jupyter notebook on IBM Watson Studio

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, libraries, folium

I am trying to install the folium library in the IBM Watson Cloud but I get the error that there is not such a module. Can someone please tell me what is wrong in the code or if I have any other type of error?

```
!conda install -c conda-forge folium
```

```
#Import libraries    
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import folium    
Latitude= 59.9111
Longitude= 10.7525
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-49c89918a981> in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 import folium`enter code here`
      5 Latitude= 59.9111
      6 Longitude= 10.7525

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium'
```

Comment: Does [this article](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Conda-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me

```
!pip install folium
```

and then

[image]